# How to use different Flask template directory from Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I want to serve up different 'look' and content for users on my flask site based on the virtualhost they use to reach the site without duplicating the entire code tree.

E.g.  going to red.mysite.com would serve up red pages  and 'red' content where the default is white.

I can do this today for the look using using a custom  static tree in the Apache config to se the css and images but I want to have a custom /template tree too so I can change the page content in my templates to 'Red' versions.

Is there a way to  set template dir from VirtualHost directives like with /static?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/mysite/static
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName red.mysite.com
        ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/mysite/red/static
        <Directory /var/www/mysite/red/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is running the application twice an option?

Comment: They are already running two instances, as mod_wsgi will separate the instances in the two ``VirtualHost``. So is issue of overriding the configuration on per ``VirtualHost`` basis.

Comment: BTW, you should look at using daemon mode and not embedded mode of mod_wsgi.

Comment: The question is, how are you telling Flask what the directory is for the templates? Assuming use of daemon mode, you can do ``import mod_wsgi; instance = mod_wsgi.process_group`` and get the name of the daemon process group and use that to trigger telling Flask to use a different template directory.

Comment: I am trying to avoid duplicating the entire application tree to make maintenance easier.  The idea of passing the process group name to Flask and branching in code sound interesting too - any good examples of this?

Answer (score 1):

Graham pointed me down the right path.

Here is how I did it:

changed conf to add in processgroup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess default
    WSGIProcessGroup default
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/mysite/static
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName red.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess red
    WSGIProcessGroup red
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/mysite/red/static
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/red/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Modified Flask app creation as follows:

```
import mod_wsgi
instance = mod_wsgi.process_group

if instance == 'red':
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='red/templates')
else:
    app = Flask(__name__)
```

Now anyone coming in on the 'Red' URL sees templates in red/templates.

Bill